# Data Binding Radio Buttons with API

Tags: angular

I made a form to get the gender of a user saved in the database, the gender is posted as radioButton. The value is sent correctly to the database and I can retrieve it also. I just want it to check the corresponding radio button. This is my `.html` code.

```html
<div class="form-group col-lg-6" ngbRadioGroup>
  <!-- Gender -->
  <label for="">Gender</label>
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary customButtons" >
    <input ngbButton type="radio" value="male" formControlName="gender"> Male
  </label>
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary customButtons">
  <input ngbButton type="radio" value="female" formControlName="gender" >Female
  </label>
</div>
```

In my `.ts` file, I usually type the following and it works if the input was textbox:

```html
this.form.controls['gender'].setValue(this.influencer.gender);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like in the docs: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/buttons/examples

The `formControlName` is to be set on element where `ngbRadioGroup` is used, instead on each individual radio button, so change your code to:

```html
<div class="form-group col-lg-6" ngbRadioGroup formControlName="gender">
  <!-- Gender -->
  <label for="">Gender</label>
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary customButtons" >
    <input ngbButton type="radio" value="male"> Male
  </label>
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary customButtons">
     <input ngbButton type="radio" value="female">Female
  </label>
</div>
```